# Why is "son" possessive in "I should rather say a very particular friend of your son's."?

Tags: possessives, double-possessives

> "I should rather say a very particular friend of your son's."

Not "of your son"? Why should I use possessive case in this statement?

Comment: You'll find the answer in the Q&A under *double possessives* or *double genitive* Also a useful explanation at: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/possessives.htm

Comment: The _'s_ is called the genitive marker. The _of_ phrase is not a genitive case marker, but just a complement of "friend". Note that if you replace "your son's" with a personal pronoun, it would have to be a genitive one ("a friend of mine / yours / ours / theirs) **not** an accusative one ("a friend of me / you / us / them")  which proves that the genitive marker is not the _of phrase_, but on the word that is complement of "of".

Comment: @BillJ, I'll take it into consideration

Comment: @RonaldSole, I've read your source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an idiom. It does not really make much sense. Some people call it the "double possessive." We also say "A friend of mine" instead of "A friend of me," "A friend of yours" instead of "A friend of you," and so on. In your original example the authorities do not allow "of your son" without the apostrophe-s (although it sounds natural to me either way); and in my examples it would be obviously incorrect to use "me" instead of "mine," etc. Where a pronoun is in that position in the expression (the object of "of"), it must be possessive.

Comment: Since when can you say "a very particular friend of you son"?

Comment: @BillJ I'm confused by this comment. The original question concerned the need for apostrophe-s, not the "r" at the end of "your." Are you asking me about the need for "r"?

Comment: No, you said, quote "In your original example it would also be correct to say "of your son" without the apostrophe-s ..."  (in my message I meant to type "your", not "you" - just a typo)

Comment: And it would be correct to say "of your son" without the apostrophe-s. He is a very particular friend of your son. No?

Comment: No it wouldn't. The genitive case marking is required.

Comment: Look, you cannot say "a very particular friend of your son". it's a simple point.

Comment: The genitive case is marked in writing by _'s_ (or by the apostrophe alone: "a friend of their sons').

Comment: @BillJ Maybe that's right. I never thought about it, but some authorities distinguish the cases according to whether the word after "of" is a person. Apparently we say "a friend of the Mayor's," but not "a suburb of the city's." Still, "a friend of your son" sounds right to me, as does "within the power of the president," "at the discretion of the judge," etc.

Comment: @Chaim, I think, you arguments are logical.

Comment: @BillJ, would you mind giving more explanations?